# label.text not changing after instance method called in appDelegate. Why would this be?

Tags: iphone, text, uilabel, appdelegate, instance-method

I have a label in a view that updates the text when a void is called. I am calling this void from my app Delegate. Using break points I can see the instance method is working and the line that changes the labels text is being call.

Only the text is not changing! This same method is called on view did load and changes perfectly.

Does anyone know of any reason why a labels text would not change if called through an instance method in the app delegate??

is there some kind of refresh function I don't know about?

Thanks

```
appDelegate.m

 -(void)callScheduler:(UILocalNotification *)notification 
{
    CompassViewController *curVC1 = [[CompassViewController alloc] init];
    AlarmViewController *curVC2 = [[AlarmViewController alloc] init];
    [curVC1 setTimeLabel];
    [curVC2.alarmTableView reloadData];

}

CompassViewController.m

- (void) setTimeLabel {

    alarmTimeLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"No Alarms", nil);   

}
```

EDIT:
...Back story, I hired someone to create a small project that I would then incorporate into my app, The only problem was that my app crashed when it ran "topViewController" because as far as my app is concerned it doesnt have one. My app is made up of view controllers that I segue between, but then the view i am currently working on IS embeded into a navigation controller. This is the original code that did work, but I think that is because the origianl project was all navigation based...

```
UINavigationController *nav = (UINavigationController *)[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController];
UIViewController *curVC = nav.topViewController;

if ([curVC isKindOfClass:[CompassViewController class]])
    [(CompassViewController *)curVC setTimeLabel];
else
    [((AlarmViewController *)curVC).alarmTableView reloadData];
```

So I guess my real question is, How do I make my app use "topViewController"?

Comment: Can you post some code the AppDelegates calls and the method you use to change the text. When the AppDelegate is calling the changing method is the view visible?

Comment: Hi Ben, I have added my code to the question. Thanks. At the moment the view is visible as im testing this, but won't always be..

Comment: Does your viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear change alarmTimeLabel, is it an IBOutlet or are you initialising it in code , if so are you doing this in the init method? Sorry about getting back to this so late. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Yes the viewWillAppear calls the void [self setTimeLabel]; and it is an IBOutlet. No problem...I'm going no where fast with this ha. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Is there any more code that could be relevant are you able to share the project? Is the IBOutlet hooked up correctly? I can't think of anything more at the moment If you would like to send me your code I will have a deeper look for you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I have edited my question so it might make a bit more sense...

Comment: Are you adding the navigation controller to the apps window in - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions? Or is it through a storyboard. What is the value when you print (UINavigationController *)[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController]?

Comment: It is through storyboard. And the value is saying the name of the first view controller that was built when I started the project. This view is not a navigation view.

Comment: If you print the reference that the app delegate has to the label and print the reference that the first view controller that set it has, are they the same?